# monodroid CustomAdapter NotifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: xamarin.android, adapter

My problem is that `((BaseAdapter)listAdapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't work. I used timer to get news every X minutes. I've did debug and saw change of dataadapter but on screen nothing change. 
If I do a zoom new datas seen on the screen. listview click event not fired on load. after change listadapter and do a zoom click event works.

could you please help me?

```
[Activity (Label = "SportNews")]            
public class SportNews : Activity
{
    RssFeedItemAdapter listAdapter;
    JavaList<FeedItem> items = new JavaList<FeedItem>();
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.list_view);

        items = RssHelper.Instance.SportNews();

        //ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Resource.Layout.list_item, items);
        listAdapter = new RssFeedItemAdapter(this,items);

        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

        listView.Adapter = listAdapter;

        ((BaseAdapter)listAdapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.ItemClick += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs>(listView_ItemClick);

        Timer timer = new Timer(PushNews, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)); // get time from user preferences...
    }
    private void PushNews(object state)
    {
        items = RssHelper.Instance.SportNews();
        JavaList<FeedItem> feeds = new JavaList<FeedItem>();
        feeds.Add(new FeedItem()
        {
         NewsPicture = "http://www.website.com/pic/test.jpg",
         NewsTitle = "Test news",
         NewsUrl = "http://www.google.com",
        });
        listAdapter = new RssFeedItemAdapter(this,feeds);
        ((BaseAdapter)this.listAdapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    void listView_ItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get our item from the list adapter
        var item = this.listAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);

        var intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetClass(this, typeof(NewsView));
        intent.PutExtra("Url", item.NewsUrl);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize that when I refresh screen like zoom, dataadapter changed with new list.do I need to call another method after 'NotifyDataSetChanged()'

Comment: Also listView_ItemClick doesn't fire !

Comment: I found answer. Changed the PushNews method like below:  RunOnUiThread(() => 
               { 
                   listAdapter.UpdateFeeds(items);
                   ((BaseAdapter)this.listAdapter).NotifyDataSetChanged(); 
               });

Comment: Yes, the issue with your code originally is that you were creating a new list adapter each time in PushNews(), but the ListView would still be using the old adapter you originally created in OnCreate().